# Highlight text based upon incoming link

Tags: html, anchor

Is there a way to highlight text based upon an incoming link.

Here is what I am trying to achieve.  I have a page that has several links to anchors on another page.  In addition to going to the named anchor on the child page, can I also make the text of the anchor link on the child page bold.

i.e.

```
Parent Page
 Dog
 Car
 Tree

Child Page
 Dog-Lab
 Car-Audi
 Tree-Pine
```

So if you were to click on Car on the parent page, it would take you to the Car info on the child page, and Car would be bold (but Dog and Tree would not).

Answer (score 1):

basically what you want to do is use a jquery or javascript function to get the anchorlink.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var anchorlink = url.split('#');
```

this will leave you with an array ["page url", "anchor"]

so you can use anchor[1] to get the string of the anchorlink.

then you can use jquery to find the element with an id that matches anchor[1] and set the font-weight:700

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#'+anchor[1]).css('font-weight','700');
})
```

or if you have a class for bold styling

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#'+anchor[1]).addClass('bold');
})
```